# SSE failed: Issue after registering event listener in grails using event-push plugin

Tags: javascript, events, grails, grails-plugin

I have an application with grails version 2.3.8. I have installed event-push plugin to push notifications from server to browser. My buildConfig.groovy look like this,

```
plugins {
   build ":tomcat:7.0.42"
   compile ":events-push:1.0.M7"
} 
grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
grails.tomcat.nio=true
```

and my listener in view,

```
try {
  var grailsEvents = new grails.Events("${createLink(uri:'')}", {transport: "sse"});

  grailsEvents.on('ActiveCallNotification', function (data) {
                     console.log("GOT recording!");
  });
} catch (error) {
     console.log("ERROR: " + error.toString());
}
```

And event firing from controller,

```
def notifyActiveCall() {
        event topic: 'ActiveCallNotification',data:"hi"
}
```

My event,

```
events = {
    'ActiveCallNotification' browser: true
}
```

Now when I browse the view which contains the listener code, I got following error again and again,

```
EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection. jquery.atmosphere.js:2297 
SSE failed. Downgrading to fallback transport and resending
```

If I comment the code in view then this error does not occurs and obviously event is not entertained. Any help would be appreciated. I am using chrome.

List of plugins installed,

```
compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
compile ':cache:1.1.2'
compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.1.1.3"
compile ':jaxrs:0.10'
compile ":quartz:1.0.1"
compile ":joda-time:1.4"
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":grails-melody:1.53.0"
compile ":quartz-monitor:1.0"
compile ":audit-logging:1.0.1"
compile ":executor:0.3"
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.13" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.1"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
```

Comment: When I create a new application then the same code works perfect but not in the old application. Is it possible that it is due to some plugin or some other conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your last comment (May 13 '15 at 13:37), have you tried following grails command:

```
grails clean-all
grails refresh-dependencies
```

You can also manually delete content of folder located here:

```
~/.grails
```

It helped me with similar issue, now that some time have passed, you can also check plugin update, using newer version can helped with conflict or wrong dependencies.